# Intent error - how to fix? (cannot find symbol class Intent)

Tags: android

I am new to android studio.

I have an error using intent in android studio.
I followed the steps on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rQILkqDpWU&t=5s)

I have a button that when clicked will be directed to an Activity but its not working.

Here are my codes

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

public void addItem(View view)
{
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, AddFood.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
}
```

Comment: This is not your full code.

Comment: Please post the full code.

Comment: AddFood => is activity? if no  than  you create to   AddFood.java  and also add it on AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Yes AddFood is my activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an attribute in XML *android:onClick*

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button_really"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Awesome!"
    android:onClick="addItem" />
```

Now you need to define method with same name in your JAVA file

```
public void addItem(View v) {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, AddFood.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
}
```

Last and most important part, make sure both Activities are defined in your **Manifest** file :)